# onActivityCreated is called whenever toggleButton is clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, adapter

I have a toggle button in fragment initialised inside adapter class and it is working as favourite list button which adds the product to the firebase database if it's clicked and remove it when it's clicked again.

```
addToCart.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (customer.userId != null) {
                mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                mCustomerRefernce = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Favorite").child(customer.userId);
                cmObej = getItem(position);
                if (isChecked) {
                    mCustomerRefernce.child(cmObej.getId()).setValue(true);
                    addToCart.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_filledstar_blue2_24dp));
                } else {
                    mCustomerRefernce.child(cmObej.getId()).removeValue();
                    addToCart.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_star_border_blue2_24dp));
                }
            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                        .setTitle("Alert")
                        .setMessage("Can't add to the list, do you want to sign in?")
                        .setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Signin2.class);
                                getContext().startActivity(i); }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that whenever it clicked a new activity is initialised as you see here

```
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 9574193
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 9574270
```

what do you think the problem is??

Comment: when u start a activity , activity life cycle come to pass

Comment: Sorry what did you mean? The same activity is reapeated each time I clicked the toggle button

Answer (score 0):

When a dialog comes on top of an existing activity, then existing activity will move to **partially invisible state** by calling `onPause()`.

If the user returns to your activity from the paused state, (closed dialog in this case),the system resumes it and calls the `onResume()` method.

Your activity embeds fragment,  [onActivityCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) will be called when activity resume.